# Git-refs-error trying many time but can't solving error. how cant I fixed error?

Tags: github

I am trying lots of times to transfer my code on the GitHub account but showing an error. I am trying to solve the error. but I can't solve it. basically, I want to transfer my code new GitHub account

```
error: src refspec main does not match any error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/rajathakur1988/dashboard-demo-api.git'
```

[image]

List item

1. List item